# How to perform deconvolution in Keras/ Theano?

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to implement deconvolution  in Keras. My model definition is as follows:

```
model=Sequential()


model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3,border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I want to perform deconvolution or transposed convolution on the output given by the first convolution layer i.e. `convolution2d_1`.

Lets say the feature map we have after first convolution layer is `X` which is of `(9, 32, 32, 32)` where 9 is the no of images of dimension `32x32` I have passed through the layer. The weight matrix of the first layer obtained by `get_weights()` function of Keras. The dimension of weight matrix is `(32, 3, 3, 2)`.

The code I am using for performing transposed convolution is

```
 conv_out = K.deconv2d(self.x, W, (9,3,32,32), dim_ordering = "th")
 deconv_func = K.function([self.x, K.learning_phase()], conv_out)
 X_deconv = deconv_func([X, 0 ])
```

But getting error:

```
 CorrMM shape inconsistency:
  bottom shape: 9 32 34 34
  weight shape: 3 32 3 3
  top shape: 9 32 32 32 (expected 9 3 32 32)
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily use [Deconvolution2D](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/#deconvolution2d) layer.

Here is what you are trying to achieve:

```
batch_sz = 1
output_shape = (batch_sz, ) + X_train.shape[1:]
conv_out = Deconvolution2D(3, 3, 3, output_shape, border_mode='same')(model.layers[0].output)

deconv_func = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], [conv_out])

test_x = np.random.random(output_shape)
X_deconv = deconv_func([test_x, 0 ])
```

But its better to create a functional model which will help both for training and prediction..

```
batch_sz = 10
output_shape = (batch_sz, ) + X_train.shape[1:]
conv_out = Deconvolution2D(3, 3, 3, output_shape, border_mode='same')(model.layers[0].output)

model2 = Model(model.input, [model.output, conv_out])
model2.summary()
model2.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'mse'], optimizer='adam')
model2.fit(X_train, [Y_train, X_train], batch_size=batch_sz)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Keras, *Conv2DTranspose* layer perform transposed convolution in other terms deconvolution. It supports both backend lib i.e. Theano & Keras.

[Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose) says:

> **Conv2DTranspose**
>
> Transposed convolution layer (sometimes called Deconvolution).
>
> The need for transposed convolutions generally arises from the desire
>   to use a transformation going in the opposite direction of a normal
>   convolution, i.e., from something that has the shape of the output of
>   some convolution to something that has the shape of its input while
>   maintaining a connectivity pattern that is compatible with said
>   convolution.